# Linked List inside a linked list with templates

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I am basically building a database structure which I can add leagues,football teams and fixtures to. I have made a linked list template and have a linked list of fixtures in each team and linked list of teams in each league. I also have a linked list of leagues within my `dataBase` class. I have managed to add the functionality to add a League to the database but now I cannot add a team. I have stepped through my add function and it assigns the correct values but when returning from the function the `team_list` linked list in the specified league is empty.

Here is my `addTeam` function in the database.

```
void Database::addTeam(Team team)
{
    Node<League>* ptr = league_list.getHead();

    while(ptr!=0)
    {
        // if the team's league matches current in the list add to this league
        if(ptr->getData().getLeagueName()==team.getLeagueName())
        {
            ptr->getData().getTeamList().add(team);
            return;
        }
        else // doesn't match so go to next league in list
        {
            ptr=ptr->getNextNode();
        }
    }
    if(ptr==NULL) // if not found prompt user
    {
        throw exception(ERRORMSG);
    }
}
```

Here is my add function within the linked list. When I step through in the debugger this appears to modify and alter the intended values. However, when it returns from this function back to the `addTeam` function in Database nothing has changed.

```
template<class data>
void LinkedList<data>::add(data a)
{
    Node<data> *nodePtr;
    nodePtr=new Node<data>(a);

    nodePtr->setNextPointer(0);

    if(head==0) // if head is empty
    {
        head=nodePtr; // make the new node the first node
        head->setPreviousPointer(0); // make the new node point to null
    }

    else
    {
        if(nodePtr==0) // if head is null
        {
            last=0; // if list unoccupied _last is null
        }
        while(nodePtr->getNextNode()!=0)
        {
            last=nodePtr->getNextNode();
        }
        nodePtr->setPreviousPointer(last);
        // set the old last node to point to the new node
        last->setNextPointer(nodePtr);
    }

    last=nodePtr;       // point to the new end of list
    current=nodePtr;    // set the current node to the last in list
}
```

I would be really grateful for any help on why this does this happens.

Comment: You won't get much attention *without* the [c++] tag. Also, there's no syntax highlighting if you don't include a language tag.

Comment: I hope you're doing this as an exercise, not to reinvent the wheel: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)

Comment: What your `getTeamList` function looks like?

Comment: I'm doing this as an exercise to get used to templates, I have a getData() function that looks like this `template<class data>data Node<data>::getData() { return a; }` where a is the data stored in the node

Comment: So you return a copy of the data stored in the node, then manipulate that copy, insert an element in the list or whatever, then look at the original data and wonder why it is unchanged. You can fix it in two ways, one bad an one good. Bad: learn about pointers and references, return one of those. Good: forget about pointers and references, learn about the Law of Demeter instead. Good luck.

Comment: I have sorted this now by having an add team function within the League class rather than using getters and setters. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your `addTeam` function:

```
template<class data>
void LinkedList<data>::add(data a)
{
    Node<data> *nodePtr;
    nodePtr=new Node<data>(a);

    // this should not be necessary, do that in the constructor of Node
    nodePtr->setNextPointer(0);

    if(head==0) // if head is empty
    {
        head=nodePtr; // make the new node the first node
        // this is not necessary, nodePtr already has been set up above
        // not to have a next node
        // head->setPreviousPointer(0); // make the new node point to null
    }
    else
    {
        // this check will never fail; what do you want to check here?
        if(nodePtr==0) // if head is null
        {
            last=0; // if list unoccupied _last is null
        }

        // this loop will never run
        /*
        while(nodePtr->getNextNode()!=0)
        {
            last=nodePtr->getNextNode();
        }
        */
        // either you have stored a Node<data>* last as member of LinkedList
        // or you need something like
        Node<data>* last = head;
        while(last->getNextNode() != 0)
        {
            last = last->getNextNode();
        }

        nodePtr->setPreviousPointer(last);
        // set the old last node to point to the new node
        last->setNextPointer(nodePtr);
    }

    last=nodePtr;       // point to the new end of list
    current=nodePtr;    // set the current node to the last in list
}
```

Comment: I have edited the linked list add code with your changes and is still not working. The add function was working and still is now I have added your changes for adding a league so I am really confused why it is not working for adding a team. Here is my addTeam function now